# ChartJS with ReactJS old dataset labels remaining when data changes

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am passing the following to my chart:

```
if ($mode == 'margin') {
        $datasets = [[
            'label' => 'Invoiced margin',
            'backgroundColor' => "rgba(122, 208, 94, 0.3)",
            'borderColor' => "rgba(122, 208, 94, 1)",
            'lineTension' => 0.2,
            'data' => [],
            'hidden' => false
        ], [
            'label' => 'Invoiced target',
            'backgroundColor' => "rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.3)",
            'borderColor' => "rgba(160, 160, 160, 1)",
            'lineTension' => 0.2,
            'data' => [],
            'hidden' => false
        ]];
    } else if ($mode == 'activity') {
        $datasets = [[
            'label' => '# of companies targeted',
            'backgroundColor' => "rgba(255, 176, 92, 0.3)",
            'borderColor' => "rgba(255, 176, 92, 1)",
            'lineTension' => 0.2,
            'data' => [],
            'hidden' => true
        ], [
            'label' => 'Targeted target',
            'backgroundColor' => "rgba(251, 255, 143, 0.3)",
            'borderColor' => "rgba(251, 255, 143, 1)",
            'lineTension' => 0.2,
            'data' => [],
            'hidden' => true
        ], [
            'label' => 'Stages aquired',
            'backgroundColor' => "rgba(77, 255, 184, 0.3)",
            'borderColor' => "rgba(77, 255, 184, 1)",
            'lineTension' => 0.2,
            'data' => [],
            'hidden' => false
        ], [
            'label' => 'Stage target',
            'backgroundColor' => "rgba(176, 255, 143, 0.3)",
            'borderColor' => "rgba(176, 255, 143, 1)",
            'lineTension' => 0.2,
            'data' => [],
            'hidden' => false
        ], [
            'label' => 'Intros sent',
            'backgroundColor' => "rgba(175, 26, 255, 0.3)",
            'borderColor' => "rgba(175, 26, 255, 1)",
            'lineTension' => 0.2,
            'data' => [],
            'hidden' => true
        ], [
            'label' => 'Intro target',
            'backgroundColor' => "rgba(214, 138, 255, 0.3)",
            'borderColor' => "rgba(214, 138, 255, 1)",
            'lineTension' => 0.2,
            'data' => [],
            'hidden' => true
        ]];
    } else if ($mode == 'calls') {
        $datasets = [[
            'label' => 'Outbound call time actual',
            'backgroundColor' => "rgba(255, 176, 92, 0.3)",
            'borderColor' => "rgba(255, 176, 92, 1)",
            'lineTension' => 0.2,
            'data' => [],
            'hidden' => false
        ], [
            'label' => 'Outbound call time target',
            'backgroundColor' => "rgba(251, 255, 143, 0.3)",
            'borderColor' => "rgba(251, 255, 143, 1)",
            'lineTension' => 0.2,
            'data' => [],
            'hidden' => false
        ]];
    }
```

If I toggle between 'margin' and 'calls' mode, the labels for the legends at the top of my chart change properly. However, if I choose 'activity' I get the labels as expected, but then when I change back to 'margin' or 'calls' the labels from 'activity' remain at the top, with the first two being replaced.

Is this a bug with ChartJS? I have tried creating the charts in a number of different ways but I still get this problem.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: which version of chart.js  are you using?

Comment: "react-chartjs-2": "^2.0.0"

Comment: have you tried this in pure chart.js rather than this wrapper? do you get the same issue?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle or plunker showing the issue?